# Arabic text output php mysql utf-8 conversion issue

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, arabic

I'm importing data from Oracle database to MySQL tables.

I have set my MySQL table charset as `utf8_general_ci` and database and table name with field column value set as `utf-8` as well.

Now, When I fetch the result, it prints like, which is with `? sign`:

```
مرحبا العال� - 5
```

I have my utf value in column is `Ù…Ø±Ø­Ø¨Ø§ Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø§Ù„Ù`

When I compare this string with Oracle string, it shows proper value - exact copy of Oracle database and there it shows perfect string in Arabic.

I have set my html meta with utf-8 as well

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
```

If I set mysql query as below, it shows junk characters:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;");
```

Followed everything possible found over stack and other sites, and still getting an error.

Please help !

Comment: please paste the original characters , and the equivalent arabic character that you want to show up !

Comment: @ProllyGeek utf chars: Ù…Ø±Ø­Ø¨Ø§ Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø§Ù„Ù… and orig text: مرحبا العالم, while my page output text: مرحبا العال�

Comment: What is the charset of the data in the oracle database.

Comment: @Musa I am not sure, however it should be utf-8 I believe

Comment: The recommended encoding is Unicode UTF-8 (the equivalent for Oracle databases is AL32UTF8)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you save the php-file without [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)? If not, try it. [Potential issues with the UTF-8 BOM](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark#problems)

---

Further try with 'utf-8' using single quotes and without SET CHARACTER_SET

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

and with charset utf-8 in the html-document header:

```
header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

with pdo you should have this

```
$_dbhandler = new PDO(PDO_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8"));
```