# An empty attribute in DOM returns an unexpected fallback value

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, getattribute

I have retrieved the content of this webpage `http://www.dw.com/ar/تقرير-استخباري-اميركي-القاعدة-تسيطر-على-غرب-العراق/a-2251369` and saved it into `$webpage`.

**PLEASE NOTE**:

In this webpage, there are a number of `<meta>` tags. One of those meta-tags is the culprit and is causing some problems. This meta-tag is `<meta property="og:description" content="" />`. Note that the value of `content` is an empty string.

I am reading the content of webpage as follows:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.dw.com/ar/تقرير-استخباري-اميركي-القاعدة-تسيطر-على-غرب-العراق/a-2251369';

$webpage = file_get_contents($url);

$og_entry_title = "";
$og_entry_content = "";

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($webpage);

$meta_tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

foreach ($meta_tags as $meta_tag) {

    if ($meta_tag->getAttribute('property') == 'og:title') {
        $og_entry_title = $meta_tag->getAttribute('content');
    }

    if ($meta_tag->getAttribute('property') == 'og:description') {
        $og_entry_content = $meta_tag->getAttribute('content');
    }

}

// print the results
echo
'$og_entry_title: ' . $og_entry_title
.PHP_EOL.
'$og_entry_content: ' . $og_entry_content;
```

When I finish, I have the following values for `$og_entry_title` and `$og_entry_content`:

> ```
> $og_entry_title: TOP STORIES | DW.COM
> $og_entry_content: News and analysis of the top international and European topics Current affairs and background information on poltics, business, science, culture, globalization and the environment.
> ```

Please  note the following in the result:

`$og_entry_title` is correct and contains the page title, so no problem here

`$og_entry_content` gives a different value from what I was expecting. I would expect an empty string to be saved in `$og_entry_content`; however the string *"News and analysis of the top international and European topics Current affairs and background information on poltics, business, science, culture, globalization and the environment."* is saved. This string appears to be a fallback value (or default value) that is returned whenever a metatag contains an empty string.

After further investigation, it turned out that the `go:description` is getting its meta-tag value from the `http://www.dw.com` webpage. It seems that this happened because my webpage contained an empty string, The returned value is retrieved from the root page of the site.

I have the following questions about `$og_entry_content`:

1. How do I ensure that the empty string (not the fallback value) is saved into `$og_entry_content`?
2. Why is this fallback value from the root page being returned anyway?

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. for me, at the end of the script `var_dump($og_entry_content);` results in `string(0) ""`

Comment: haven't u tried the alternative `get_meta_tags`, looking at this end, this should be an empty string

Comment: @RodrigoDuterte - `get_meta_tags` causes the same problem.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII - Thanks for your comment. I edited the quesion to be more reflective of the problem. Now you should be able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

Your web address has special characters in it that need to be [URL encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

---

## Explanation

First of all, the assumption that...

> `$og_entry_title` is correct and contains the page title, so no problem here

...is wrong.

This title:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="تقرير استخباري اميركي: القاعدة تسيطر على غرب العراق | أخبار | DW.COM | 28.11.2006" />
```

is not the same as this title:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="TOP STORIES | DW.COM" />
```

Secondly, most modern browsers are awesome enough to do URL encoding on the fly and still display the special characters in the address bar.

You can [see the response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9183272/4233593) from the web server for more information.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.dw.com/ar/تقرير-استخباري-اميركي-القاعدة-تسيطر-على-غرب-العراق/a-2251369';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Then, after your curl_exec call:
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
echo '
header
------
'.substr($response, 0, $header_size);
```

The results show that it doesn't recognize the association between the URL and that page:

> ```
> header
> ------
> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
> Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
> Location: /
> Content-Length: 0
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
> X-Varnish: 99639238
> Date: Thu, 16 Jun 2016 15:42:51 GMT
> Connection: keep-alive
> ```

[HTTP Response Code `301`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) is a notice to (permanently) redirect to another page. `Location: /` indicates that you should just go to **the home page**. This is a common sloppy practice to just send someone to the home page when they don't know what to do with you.

Curl won't follow redirects by default, which is how we're able to examine the 301 response header. But `file_get_contents` will follow redirects, which is why you're getting different content than you expect. (With possible exceptions: there is a [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53018) where some notice that it doesn't always follow redirects.)

Note that the home page *does* have `content` in its `og:description`:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('http://www.dw.com/ar/تقرير-استخباري-اميركي-القاعدة-تسيطر-على-غرب-العراق/a-2251369');
```

Results in this output:

> ...
>
> ```
> <meta property="og:description" content="News and analysis of the top international and European topics Current affairs and background information on poltics, business, science, culture, globalization and the environment. " />
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> <meta property="og:title" content="TOP STORIES | DW.COM" />
> ```
>
> ...

---

## Solution

First thing you need to do is [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) the web address:

```
$url = rawurlencode($url);
```

Then realize that `rawurlencode` is poorly named because a [valid URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) will contain the HTML protocol `http://` or `https://` and could also contain slashes to delimit parts. This is problematic because `rawurlencode` will convert colons `:` to `%3A` and slashes `/` to `%2F` which makes for an invalid URL like `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dw.com%2Far%2F...`. It should have been named `rawurlencode_parts_of_URL`, but they didn't ask me :) And to quote Phil Karlton in their defense:

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and ***naming things***.

So convert the slashes and colons back to their original form:

```
$url = str_replace('%3A',':',str_replace('%2F','/',$url));
```

Finally, the last thing you need to do is [send a header to your clients to let them know what kind of font encoding to expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20731488/4233593).

```
header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Otherwise, your clients might be reading some [gobbledygook](http://www.wordcentral.com/cgi-bin/student?book=Student&va=gobbledygook) that could look something like this:

> ØªÙ‚Ø±ÙŠØ± Ø§Ø³ØªØ®Ø¨Ø§Ø±ÙŠ Ø§Ù…ÙŠØ±ÙƒÙŠ: Ø§Ù„Ù‚Ø§Ø¹Ø¯Ø© ØªØ³ÙŠØ·Ø± Ø¹Ù„Ù‰ ØºØ±Ø¨ Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø§Ù

---

## Final Product

```
<?php

// let's see error output on screen while in development
// remove these lines for production, and use log files only
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$url = 'http://www.dw.com/ar/تقرير-استخباري-اميركي-القاعدة-تسيطر-على-غرب-العراق/a-2251369';

// URL encode special chars
$url = rawurlencode($url);

// fix colons and slashses for valid URL
$url = str_replace('%3A',':',str_replace('%2F','/',$url));

// make request
$webpage = file_get_contents($url);

$og_entry_title = "";
$og_entry_content = "";

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($webpage);

$meta_tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

foreach ($meta_tags as $meta_tag) {

    if ($meta_tag->getAttribute('property') == 'og:title') {
        $og_entry_title = $meta_tag->getAttribute('content');
    }

    if ($meta_tag->getAttribute('property') == 'og:description') {
        $og_entry_content = $meta_tag->getAttribute('content');
    }

}

// set the character set for the client
header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

// print the results
echo
'$og_entry_title: ' . $og_entry_title
.PHP_EOL.
'$og_entry_content: ' . $og_entry_content;
```

Results in this output:

> ```
> $og_entry_title: تقرير استخباري اميركي: القاعدة تسيطر على غرب العراق | أخبار | DW.COM | 28.11.2006
> $og_entry_content:
> ```

---

## Addendum

If you're looking at your [error logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php), and you really *should **always*** be looking at your error logs when developing, then you'll notice a litany of warnings:

> ```
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <html> tag in Entity, line: 4 in ...
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <html> tag in Entity, line: 5 in ...
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <html> tag in Entity, line: 6 in ...
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <html> tag in Entity, line: 7 in ...
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID topMetaInner already defined in Entity, line: 300 in ...
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID langSelectTrigger already defined in Entity, line: 315 in ...
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 546 in ...
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 546 in ...
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 548 in ...
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 548 in ...
> ```

This is because you're trying to use the DOMDocument class with [in-valid HTML and not well-formed XML documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html). But this is a topic for a different question.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing detailed answer. I have done everything you mentioned, but I still get that problem. I think it is a problem with the server not sending me back the proper page to begin with. I wil investigate further.

Comment: really? you *don't* get the same output result that I show when running the "Final Product" script? I have updated the answer to show errors on screen. what is your output?